# dynamically removing and adding onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically generating html string and add event to it like below

```
htmlString = "<a href='#' class='save' onclick='callFunc(" + 4 + ")'>";
```

I now need to dynamically remove this onclick event and readd again with different Id.

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `callFunc` is a named function, you can nullify `element.onclick` then add a new event that is bound to your new id:

```
var newId = 10; 
var saveLink = document.querySelector('.save');
saveLink.onclick = null;
saveLink.onclick = callFunc.bind(saveLink, newId);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mqyyf0xu/

**Edit**: with the new information that you want to increment a count when the user clicks the link, I think you should modify your approach to something like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="like" data-likes="0">Likes <span class="like-count">0</span></a>
```

Javascript:

```
var likeButton = document.querySelector('.like');

likeButton.onclick = function() {
   var likeCountDisplay = this.querySelector('.like-count');
   var likeCount = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-likes'), 10) + 1;
   this.setAttribute('data-likes', likeCount);
   likeCountDisplay.textContent = likeCount;
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mqyyf0xu/2/

Comment: Is it not possible to change the html and instead of showing onclick="callFunc(4)" it should change to onclick="callFunc(10)"

Comment: Not once it has been injected into the DOM

Comment: is it possible to change of text in span tag in dom? or that too not possible?

Comment: i modified your fiddle. I want to increment value of id on every click but its not happening. I am implementing this likes functionality we have in facebook. It will increase count. https://jsfiddle.net/mqyyf0xu/1/

Comment: @Happy I updated my answer to hopefully show you how to accomplish your goal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78386/discussion-between-happy-and-rob-m).